# If $X$ is $T_1$, any point of $X $is $G_{\delta}$ and any discrete subset is enumerable then $|X| \leq c$

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

I need to show that, if $X$ is $T_1$, any point of $X$ is $G_{\delta}$ and any discrete subset is enumerable then $|X| \leq c$.

the suggestion is to use the theorem of Erdős-Rado: Let $k$ be an infinite cardinal, $E$ a set such that $|E|>2^k$ and suppose $[E]^2= \bigcup_{\alpha < k}P_{\alpha} $. then exist $\alpha<k$ and $A \subset E$ such that $|A|>k$ and   $[A]^2 \subset P_ \alpha$.

Comment: Look in Juhasz' book cardinal functions in topology, it's probably in there. So you can maybe show $|X| \le 2^{\psi(X)s(X)}$ for $X$ $T_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $x \in X$ fix a countable sequence of neighbourhoods $V_n(x), n \in \omega$ such that

$$\bigcap_{n \in \omega} V_n(x) =\{x\}$$

using that each point is a $G_\delta$. Fix some linear order $<$ on $X$ and
define for each $n,m \in \omega$: $$I(n,m) = \{\{x,y\} \in [X]^2: x < y \land y \notin V_n(x) \land x \notin V_m(y)\}$$

Check that $X$ being $T_1$ implies that

$$[X]^2 = \bigcup_{(n,m) \in \omega\times \omega} I(n,m)$$

So if were the case that $|X| > 2^{\aleph_0}$ we could apply the Erdős-Rado theorem  and get a subset $D$ of $X$ of size $>\aleph_0$ (so $D$ is uncountable) so that there is a fixed $(n_0, m_0)$ pair such that for all $x,y \in D$, $\{x,y\} \in I(n_0,m_0)$ (a very nice infinite Ramsey theorem).

By construction we have that for each $p \in D$ we have $\{p\} =D \cap V_{n_0}(p) \cap V_{m_0}(p)$ so that each point of $D$ is isolated in $D$, so $D$ is uncountable and discrete, which is a contradiction with the assumptions on $X$. So $|X| \le \mathfrak{c}$ must hold.

[Adapted from 2.15 in Juhasz' book *cardinal functions in topology*, the general proof shows that $|X| \le 2^{\psi(X)s(X)}$, where $\psi(X)$ is the pseudocharacter of $X$ and $s(X)$ the spread of $X$.]